# aws elasticbeanstalk environment failing with 502 when sprinboot app deployed through codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a springboot app, with below buildspec.yml,

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto17
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn clean install -DskipTests
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/*.jar
  discard-paths: yes
```

In aws codePipieline I see build is deployed but in aws EB environment I am seeing 502 error when checked for the environment,

and tried to check logs but I am seeing request logs failed and environment started updating which takes long time, once it updated again I tried to get logs, again environment started updating.